# Laravel 4: add whereIn clause to a join condition

Tags: php, join, laravel, eloquent, where-in

I want to run the below query

```
SELECT * FROM order_item JOIN order ON (order_item.order_id = order.id AND order.order_status IN ('payment_completed','refund_requested')) WHERE order_item.item_id=1;
```

I tried like below.

```
OrderItem::join('order', function($join){
            $join->on('order.id','=','order_item.order_id');
            $join->whereIn('order.order_status',array('payment_completed','refund_requested'));
    })->where('order_item.item_id','=','1')->get();
```

I know this is wrong. What is the right way to use whereIn clause in join condition?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't do that. Just put that `whereIn` outside the `join` clause, you don't need it there anyway.

Comment: Thanks @JarekTkaczyk . I did as like you said after that. But just wanted to konw is there anyway to include the whereIn clause with join condition in laravel

Answer (score 0):

Hell, I have another option for do this thing.

## You can use FIND_IN_SET('ABC','ABC,CDE,DEF,XYZ');

It will return true if condition true so you can add this condition in join cause.

```
OrderItem::join('order', function($join){
        $join->on('order.id','=','order_item.order_id')
        $join->on(\DB::raw("FIND_IN_SET(order.order_status,'payment_completed,refund_requested')"),"=",\DB::raw('"1"'));

})->where('order_item.item_id','=','1')->get();
```