# convert SQL query to query builder style

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, octobercms

Im trying days to understand how I can convert a SQL query to a query builder style in laravel.

My SQL query is:

```
$tagid = Db::select("SELECT `id` FROM `wouter_blog_tags` WHERE `slug` = '".$this->param('slug')."'");

$blog = Db::select("SELECT * 
            FROM `wouter_blog_posts` 
            WHERE `published` IS NOT NULL 
            AND `published` = '1'
            AND `published_at` IS NOT NULL 
            AND `published_at` < NOW()
            AND (

            SELECT count( * ) 
            FROM `wouter_blog_tags` 
            INNER JOIN `wouter_blog_posts_tags` ON `wouter_blog_tags`.`id` = `wouter_blog_posts_tags`.`tags_id` 
            WHERE `wouter_blog_posts_tags`.`post_id` = `wouter_blog_posts`.`id` 
            AND `id` 
            IN (
             '".$tagid[0]->id."'
            )) >=1
            ORDER BY `published_at` DESC 
            LIMIT 10 
            OFFSET 0");
```

Where I now end up to convert to the query builder is:

```
   $test = Db::table('wouter_blog_posts')
->where('published', '=', 1)
->where('published', '=', 'IS NOT NULL')
->where('published_at', '=', 'IS NOT NULL')
->where('published_at', '<', 'NOW()')
  ->select(Db::raw('count(*) wouter_blog_tags'))
->join('wouter_blog_posts_tags', function($join)
{ 
$join->on('wouter_blog_tags.id', '=', 'wouter_blog_posts_tags.tags_id')
->on('wouter_blog_posts_tags.post_id', '=', 'wouter_blog_posts.id')
->whereIn('id', $tagid[0]->id);
})
->get();
```

I have read that I can't use whereIn in a join. The error i now get:

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\JoinClause::whereIn()

I realy dont know how I can convert my SQL to query builder. I hope when I see a good working conversion of my query I can understand how I have to do it next time.

Comment: I haven't tried this, but maybe use `->whereRaw('id IN ?', [$tagid[0]->id])`. Just make sure the bindings parameter at the end is an array. However, I don't know why you're using WHERE IN for one value - `$tagid[0]->id`. Does this return an array or something?

Here's an alternative solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26913776/laravel-4-add-wherein-clause-to-a-join-condition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work for me:

> DB::table('wouter_blog_posts')
>       ->whereNotNull('published')
>       ->where('published', 1)
>       ->whereNotNull('published_at')
>       ->whereRaw('`published_at` < NOW()')
>       ->whereRaw("(SELECT count(*) 
>               FROM `wouter_blog_tags` 
>               INNER JOIN `wouter_blog_posts_tags` ON `wouter_blog_tags`.`id` = `wouter_blog_posts_tags`.`tags_id` 
>               WHERE `wouter_blog_posts_tags`.`post_id` = `wouter_blog_posts`.`id` 
>               AND `id` 
>               IN (
>                '".$tagid."'
>               )) >=1")
>       ->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')
>       ->skip(0)
>       ->take(10)
>       ->paginate($this->property('postsPerPage'));

Answer (score 0):

The following Query Builder code will give you the exact SQL query you have within your `DB::select`:

```
DB::table('wouter_blog_posts')
    ->whereNotNull('published')
    ->where('published', 1)
    ->whereNotNull('published_at')
    ->whereRaw('`published_at` < NOW()')
    ->where(DB::raw('1'), '<=', function ($query) use ($tagid) {
        $query->from('wouter_blog_tags')
            ->select('count(*)')
            ->join('wouter_blog_posts_tags', 'wouter_blog_tags.id', '=', 'wouter_blog_posts_tags.tags_id')
            ->whereRaw('`wouter_blog_posts_tags`.`post_id` = `wouter_blog_posts`.`id`')
            ->whereIn('id', [$tagid[0]->id]);
    })
    ->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')
    ->skip(0)
    ->take(10)
    ->get();
```

The subquery condition had to be reversed because you can't have a subquery as the first parameter of the `where` method and still be able to bind the condition value. So it's `1 <= (subquery)` which is equivalent to `(subquery) >= 1`. The query generated by the above code will look like this:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM `wouter_blog_posts` 
WHERE `published` IS NOT NULL 
       AND `published` = 1 
       AND `published_at` IS NOT NULL 
       AND `published_at` < Now() 
       AND 1 <= (SELECT `count(*)` 
                 FROM `wouter_blog_tags` 
                      INNER JOIN `wouter_blog_posts_tags` 
                              ON `wouter_blog_tags`.`id` = 
                                 `wouter_blog_posts_tags`.`tags_id` 
                 WHERE `wouter_blog_posts_tags`.`post_id` = 
                       `wouter_blog_posts`.`id` 
                        AND `id` IN ( ? )) 
ORDER  BY `published_at` DESC 
LIMIT  10 offset 0
```

---

My process when creating more complex queries is to first create them and try them out in a SQL environment to make sure they work as indended. Then I implement them step by step with the Query Builder, but instead of using `get()` at the end of the query, I use `toSql()` which will give me a string representation of the query that will be generated by the Query Builder, allowing me to compare that to my original query to make sure it's the same.

Comment: the query builder works completely differently than I would expect. I do not get this: ->'1', '<=', function ($query) use ($tagid[0]->id). There is no colum 1 The error I get: syntax error, unexpected ''1'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'

Comment: That was my mistake, I didn't notice that because I inverted the condition, the first parameter of the `where` method gets quoted because its expecting a column there. I've updated my answer to use `DB::raw` which fixes that.